# TypeScript + Webpack 2 - imported modules aren't showing up in bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, electron

I'm using TS 2.3.x and Webpack 2.x - this is an electron project which I'm slowly converting from JS to TS.

The gist of my webpack config is

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "../build"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
                use: ["awesome-typescript-loader"],
                exclude: [/node_modules/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                use: ["babel-loader"],
                exclude: [/node_modules/]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".json"]
    }
};
```

I'm using Hot module replacement, `LoaderOptionsPlugin({ debug: true })`, and named modules plugins, but none of those should effect the bundle output causing the issue I'm seeing.

For Awesome Typescript Loader, I'm using

```
{ 
    "babelOptions": {},
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "useBabel": true,
    "useCache": false
}
```

see here for info: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#loader-options

The issue is that I have a TypeScript module like

```
// settings-modal.tsx
import * as React from "react";

...

import Modal from "../base/modal";
import ModalHeader from "../base/modal-header";

class SettingsModal extends React.Component<any, any> {
    ...

    render() {
        // I use both Modal and ModalHeader here
    }
}
```

`Modal` and `ModalHeader` are both standard React components and they're exported as the module's default. I've tried converting both them to TS, but the imports are still missing from the bundle.

But when the bundle is compiled, the output looks like

```
...

var React = __webpack_require__("../node_modules/react/react.js");
var modal_1 = __webpack_require__("./ui/components/base/modal.js");

var SettingsModal = function (_super) {
    __extends(SettingsModal, _super);

    function SettingsModal() {
       ...
    }

    SettingsModal.prototype.render = function() {
        return React.createElement(modal_1.default, {...}, React.createElement(modal_header_1.default, ...));
    }
}

...
```

notice how `modal-header` is not imported, but `modal_header_1` is referenced.